# Select ul li from dropdownlist using jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I went really long way trying to rewrite select to ul li and style it accordingly.

So I'm thinking to ditch the idea completely, and just use normal ul li menu and some kind of jquery to make it function like select (for form submission etc).

As i wish to select the particular li once select the button , it will show up an dropdown list from ul li.

my HTML :

```
<div class="mm_main">
            <ul>
                <li>ATM<i></i></li>
                <li style="margin-bottom: 20px;">柜台<i></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

  <div class="input_01 xlmenu" id="bank_hx"><a>选择银行</a></div>
                    <input id="bankcode" type="hidden">
                    <ul id="zxtext2">
                        <li><i></i>请选择银行</li>
                    </ul>
```

my jQUERY :

```
$(".xlmenu").click(function () {

            var xlmenu = ".mmenu";
            var xlmovie = "mmenu_movie";

            //$(xlmenu).addClass(xlmovie);

            var mmenu = $(this).attr("id");


            if (mmenu == "depType")/*选择银行菜单*/ {
                $(xlmenu).eq(1).addClass(xlmovie);
                choicemenu();


            } else {
                $(xlmenu).eq(2).addClass(xlmovie);
                choicemenubank();
            }

            $(".mm_exit").click(function () {
                $(xlmenu).removeClass(xlmovie);
            });


            function choicemenu() {
                $(".mm_main li").unbind("click");
                $(".mm_main li").click(function () {
                    $(".mm_main li i").removeClass("border");
                    $(this).find("i").addClass("border");
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    if (mmenu == "depType")/*ATM选择方式菜单*/ {
                        $("#depType").text(title);
                        closemenu()
                    }
                });
            };

            function choicemenubank() {
                $(".mm_main li").unbind("click");
                $(".mm_main li").click(function () {
                    $(".mm_main li i").removeClass("border");
                    $(this).find("i").addClass("border");
                    $(xlmenu).removeClass(xlmovie);
                    var title = $(this).find("input").val();

                    var arr = title.split('#');

                    if (mmenu == "bank_hx") /*在线支付选择银行菜单*/ {
                        $("#bank_hx").text(arr[0]);
                        $("#bankcode").val(arr[1]);
                    }
                });
            };
            function closemenu() {
                $(xlmenu).removeClass(xlmovie);
            };

        });
```

Comment: I think your question is incomplete. I instrumented and created a test case here (https://jsfiddle.net/hvekeyw4/10/). Could you provide the CSS and anything missing?